# vuejs parent event once all child data is fetched

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm new to vuejs and still a bit lost as to if I should use events or vuex to know when all children's data has been fetched from the server.

For example I have a route with a structure like this:

```
<Parent>
   <Child1 />
   <Child2 />
   <Child3 />
</Parent>
```

Then in each of the child components I have a fetchData() method which retrieves the data from the server from different end points:

```
export default {        
    created() {
      // fetch data
        this.fetchData()    
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData() {
            this.$http.get('/api/dataN', {})
                .then(response => {
                    // do something
                }).catch(error => {})
        }
    }
}
```

How does the parent know once **all child data has been fetched** so the parent can perform an action?

I want to make this a generic function so in the case where another route only has two children (or more than 3) then event is always fired.

I've looked at parent hooks, but seems I am getting child data on create (component is loaded), the parent hooks are no use to me - as far as I can understand.

Example of where I need to modify DOM for parent:
[image: example]

Comment: i understand that when all the child component do their task to retrieve data you will do something in the parent component?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yes that is correct. Once all child data is retrieved I want to modify a (DOM) element in the parent - It's actually a spinner that I want to hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should emit an event from each child component and the parent component add a data property called `nb_components` which is initialized with number of components and another `count` which will be incremented every time a child component do its task :

```
export default {

  created() {
    // fetch data
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      this.$http.get('/api/dataN', {})
        .then(response => {
          this.$emit('fetch-data')
        }).catch(error => {})
    }
  }
}
```

and the parent component :

```
<Parent>
  <Child1 @fetch-data="increment"  />
  <Child2 @fetch-data="increment"  />
  <Child3 @fetch-data="increment"  />
</Parent>
```

script

```
 data(){
       return{
         count:0,
         nb_components:3
         ....
        }
      },
  methods:{
       increment(){
          this.count++;
          if(this.count==this.nb_components){
                 //stop the spinner
             }
          }
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using an async callback function. Each child component returns an async function of it's own (such as an api call) which the parent resolves and keeps a running counter of the number of times the callback has been triggered:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `<div>I take {{ timeout }} seconds to finish. <span>{{ message }}</span></div>`,
  props: ['callback'],
  data () {
    return {
      timeout: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10),
      complete: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    message () {
      return this.complete ? 'Done!' : 'Working...'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.complete = !this.complete
      
      const func = async () => {}
      
      this.callback.call(this, func)
    }, this.timeout * 1000)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      max: 10,
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    message () {
      return this.counter < this.max ? `${this.max - this.counter} Jobs remaining` : `All jobs complete!`
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async callback(func) {
      const data = await func()
      
      this.counter += 1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <child v-for="i in max" :key="i" :callback="callback" style="margin: 1rem 0;"></child>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end I did this slightly different:

1. child to maintain state of spinner
2. $emit to provide callback to parent - to switch spinner on
   / off

This isn't my full code but gives you an example of how I went resolve it.

```
<div id="app">
<div id="spinner" v-show="spinner" key=1></div>
  <child v-show="!spinner" @spinnerCallback="setSpinner" />
</div>

Vue.component('child', {
  template: `<div>this is child data</div>`,

  data() {
        return {
            tiles: '',
        }
    },
    created() {
      // start spinner
      this.$emit('spinnerCallback', 1)

      //fetch data
        this.fetchData()
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData() {
            this.$http.get('/api/dashboard', {})
                .then(response => {
                    this.tiles = response.data.tiles//,
                    this.$emit('spinnerCallback', 0)
                }).catch(error => {})
        }
    }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            spinner: null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setSpinner: function(value) {
          // toggle spinner
          if (value == 1) {
            this.spinner = true;
          } else {
            this.spinner = false;
          }
        }
    },
})
```